# use FacebookComposeViewController ,but photo can't show

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I learned this Sample code, and try to implement in my app, but the photo can't show.

[enter link description here](https://github.com/sakrist/FacebookSample)

[image]

[image]

```
- (IBAction)facebookBtn_down:(id)sender {
if (osVer >= 6.0) {
    SLComposeViewController *fbVC = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
    [fbVC setInitialText:apple_F_MSG];
    [fbVC addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:APP_URL]];
    [fbVC setCompletionHandler:^(SLComposeViewControllerResult res) {

        if (res == SLComposeViewControllerResultDone) [self AlertToukou];
    }];
    [self presentModalViewController:fbVC animated:YES];
} else {
    DEFacebookComposeViewController *fbVC = [[[DEFacebookComposeViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [fbVC setInitialText:apple_F_MSG];
    [fbVC addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:APP_URL]];
    [fbVC setCompletionHandler:^(DEFacebookComposeViewControllerResult res) {
        if (res == DEFacebookComposeViewControllerResultDone) [self AlertToukou];
        [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFullScreen;
    }];
    [self presentModalViewController:fbVC animated:YES];
}
```

}

please give me some advice,thank you!

Comment: Can you please post your code !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation page of that it says,

```
DEFacebookComposeViewController *facebookViewComposer = [[DEFacebookComposeViewController alloc] init];
self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
[facebookViewComposer setInitialText:@"Look on this"];
[facebookViewComposer addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpg"]];//<------Check This
facebookViewComposer.completionHandler = completionHandler;
[self presentViewController:facebookViewComposer animated:YES completion:^{ }];
```

You should use `addImage` function and give proper `UIImage` object than it should be working.

Comment: when i use this,than can't not request

Comment: errorError Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)"

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem：

I did not set the Key "forKey:@"source",than can't post on the wall

errorError Domain=com.facebook.sdk Code=5 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)"

```
if ([self.images count] > 0) {
        [d setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation([self.images lastObject]) forKey:@""];
        graphPath = @"me/photos";
    }
```